# Why there's no concept of Null initialization to an unsigned integer in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I was writing a code my unsigned-integer value initialized as 0 as shown below

My code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.9.0;

contract PT_StateVariable

{

    uint256  public age ;
}
```

Deploy tab

[image]

But when I tried to give it a NULL, it  gave an error.

Why there's no NULL concept (like in C++) been used in Solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solidity **doesn't exist** the concept of 'NULL' like in C++,C#,Java,...
The documentation say this:

> The concept of “undefined” or “null” values does not exist in
> Solidity, but newly declared variables always have a default value
> dependent on its type. To handle any unexpected values, you should use
> the revert function to revert the whole transaction, or return a tuple
> with a second bool value denoting success.

I recommend you to read documentation's section about [declarations](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/control-structures.html?#scoping-and-declarations):

> A variable which is declared will have an initial default value whose
> byte-representation is all zeros. The “default values” of variables
> are the typical “zero-state” of whatever the type is. For example, the
> default value for a bool is false. The default value for the uint or
> int types is 0. For statically-sized arrays and bytes1 to bytes32,
> each individual element will be initialized to the default value
> corresponding to its type. For dynamically-sized arrays, bytes and
> string, the default value is an empty array or string. For the enum
> type, the default value is its first member.

More information [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html).